# Flask - TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response

Tags: python, flask, typeerror, vercel

Flask `redirect` was working fine on localhost but after deploying to [Vercel](https://vercel.com) it is throwing error

My code -

```
try:
    return redirect(str(urlDictionary[path]), code=302)
except Exception as e:
    return e
```

Exception it is returning -

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a KeyError
```

Error -

```
[ERROR] 2021-05-24T07:22:02.390Z    6f2998c4-473a-4abc-8340-20792c0bd008    Exception on /C8F14 [GET]Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app    response = self.full_dispatch_request()  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request    rv = self.dispatch_request()  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)  File "/var/task/app.py", line 36, in RedirectShort    return redirect(str(urlDictionary[path]), code=302)KeyError: 'C8F14'127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2021 07:22:02] "GET /C8F14 HTTP/1.1" 500 290
```

Comment: `urlDictionary[path]` is raising a key-error that is being caught in the except block. Then - for some reason - you are returning that exception. Which flask does not know what do with. See: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/

Comment: @rdas actually it was working fine on localhost but in vercel it is throwing that error

Comment: Try not to catch all exceptions like that & python will show you what the error is.

Comment: @rdas yes you're right! I have edited my original post. Please check.

Comment: Ok I found the reason, which is vercel has some bugs to execute python dictionaries.